# Converting WSHttpBinding to custom

Tags: wcf, web-config, wcf-binding

I want to increase the MaxClockSkew of my binding but I don't know how can I convert my binding to a custom binding to add the MaxClockSkew element.

I really appreciate if anyone could help me converting this.

```
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="MyBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="102400">
      <readerQuotas  maxArrayLength="51200" maxStringContentLength="102400" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the online [WCF Binding Converter](http://webservices20.cloudapp.net/)

Try this:

```
<customBinding>
  <binding name="NewBinding0">    
      <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10" />

    <textMessageEncoding />
    <httpsTransport maxBufferSize="102400" maxReceivedMessageSize="102400" />
  </binding>
</customBinding>
```

Comment: I think it does convert correctly but try also the one I edited now